# App icon from deb package not showing on Gnome

Tags: linux, deb, gnome-shell

I try to setup icons to package a deb package. Here is the list of file:

```
$ dpkg-query -L fan-control 
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/fan-control
/usr/share
/usr/share/applications
/usr/share/applications/fan-control.desktop
/usr/share/icons
/usr/share/icons/hicolor
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/150x150
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/150x150/apps
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/150x150/apps/fan-control.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/fan-control.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/fan-control.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/fan-control.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/apps
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/fan-control.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps/fan-control.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/512x512
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/512x512/apps
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/512x512/apps/fan-control.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps/fan-control.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/fan-control.png
```

```
$ cat /usr/share/applications/fan-control.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Categories=Utility;
Comment=Control your fans with different behaviors
Exec=fan-control
Icon=fan-control
Name=fan-control
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

So the icon is shown when i search my app (on the cosmic launcher because i use PopOs), but is not shown on the dock (a default icon is shown instead).
I tried to use https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock, but it have the same problem. All other app icon works as expected so i assume it's on me.

I tried to manually put an svg in scalable dir:

```
$ ls /usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/app -l
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4649 déc.   7 16:14 com.system76.CosmicAppletStatusArea.svg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  349 déc.  11 00:35 fan-control.svg
```

This hasn't worked.
What should i do? I literally put every possible size available and it still doesn't works.